# Fetch API React Js Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, use-effect

I got this error from my fetch api when I pass my url fetch API from a state called url. But when I changed my url into text like 'api/provinsi' I don't get any error

> Error fetching data:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at
> position 0

```
   useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchMyAPI() {
            await fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET'
            }).then(response => {
                if(!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(response => {
                if(response.Response === 'False') {
                    throw new Error(response.Error);
                }
                setData(response.data);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("Error fetching data: ", error);
            });
        }
        fetchMyAPI();
    }, []);
```

And this is how I set my url state:

```
  useEffect(() => {
        if(idDaerah==1){
            setColumn(['no', 'nama', 'aksi']);
            setUrl('/api/provinsi');
        } else if(idDaerah==2) {
            setColumn(['no', 'nama', 'provinsi_id', 'aksi']);
            setUrl('/api/kabupaten');
        } else if(idDaerah==3) {
            setColumn(['no', 'nama', 'kabupaten_id', 'aksi']);
            setUrl('/api/kecamatan');
        } else {
            setColumn(['no', 'nama', 'kecamatan_id', 'aksi']);
            setUrl('/api/desa');
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: Your response should be a bad formatted json

Comment: What's the initial value of `url`? You probably have a problem of stale closure because `url` is not specified in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: @Yousaf I will use component many times with different fetch url. Should I create another function and pass the url as parameter?

Comment: It sounds like the response is not JSON.  So what *is* the response?  In your browser's debugging tools, check the network tab.  What is the request made?  What is the response?  How do they differ from what you expect?

Comment: @David it's an object. See the answer from bakar_dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because both `useEffect` runs at the same time, and the fetch function receive `url` as an `empty string` first time, so you need to add `url` as dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchMyAPI() {
            await fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET'
            }).then(response => {
                if(!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(response => {
                if(response.Response === 'False') {
                    throw new Error(response.Error);
                }
                setData(response.data);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("Error fetching data: ", error);
            });
        }
       if(url !== ''){ //check if url is set i.e not an empty string
        fetchMyAPI();
      }
    }, [url]); //add dependency, when url change then call api
```

OR

You can provide a default `url` like:

```
const [url, setUrl] = useState('/api/provinsi');
```